# python how to overload maybe?? the constructor

Tags: python

i have this code :

```
class random_walk:
    #ns: number of steps1d
    #np: number of particles
    #dimension : choose between 1D or 2D
    def __init__(self,ns,np,dimension=None):
        self.ns=ns
        self.np=np
        self.dimension=dimension

    def steps1d(self,ns):    
        return 2*sc.random.random_integers(0,1,size=self.ns)-1

    # The position of particles after the n-th steps1d is given from the sum of n first steps1d
    def Walk1d(self,ns):
        return sc.cumsum(random_walk.steps1d(self,self.ns)
.....
```

When i do :

```
ns=10000
np=100
dimension=2
rw1=random_walk(ns,np)  # for 1d
```

the rw1 creates an instance for the class random_walks,which has ns=10000.

Now,if for example i want to do :

```
print('walk1d(10)=',rw1.Walk1d(10))
```

it will give me 10000 size array (because if i am telling this right ,it created an instance before with 10000 ns).
So, if i want to apply the above statement in order to give me 10 size array what solutions exists?

Comment: In `Walk1d`, you should not be calling `random_walk.steps1d(self,self.ns)`. Instead just call `self.steps1d(self.ns)`.

Comment: Hello,this doesn't do nothing.Still the same.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I did what you said and i understand that i must do self.steps1d and not random_walk in order not to create instance of class but access immediately the function steps1d.But it still doesn't do whjat i want and i can't understand why

Comment: What is `sc`? Where and how do you create the _array_? You do not provide enough information for us to help you.

Comment: My mistake was in steps(see below).The sc is import scipy as sc.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def steps1d(self, ns):    
    return 2*sc.random.random_integers(0, 1, size=ns)-1

def Walk1d(self, ns=None):
    if ns is None:
        ns = self.ns
    return sc.cumsum(self.steps1d(ns))
```

Comment: Hello,it gives me "unbound method steps1d() must be called with random_walk instance as first argument (got int instance instead)"

Comment: @George Not if you do what I told you in my comment. You should read more about how to call methods in python.

Comment: @George: that was a bug in your code that I forgot to fix, but I updated the answer.

Comment: @George: turns out you had a bug in `steps1s` as well. Why are you storing `self.ns` at all if you want to specify it as a parameter to your methods?

Comment: Yes,that was the mistake.Thank you